# Referencing JSON object fields after assigning to variable in useEffect()

Tags: react-native, react-hooks

I'm attempting to retrieve a JSON object from an API call, and then set a useState variable to the response for use in my app. I am able to successfully receive the JSON response, but if I try to reference specific fields I get an error saying
`null is not an object (evaluating data.type)`. I understand that this happens because initially the `data` variable is simply null, but I'm not sure the best way to go about preventing this and I suspect I'm doing something fundamentally wrong.

Here's the function which queries the API and retrieves the response data:

```
export function searchFlightOffers(postData) {
    return getAmadeusToken().then(data => {
        const config = {
            headers: {
                'Authorization': `Bearer ${data.access_token}`
            }
        }

        return axios.post("https://test.api.amadeus.com/v2/shopping/flight-offers", postData, config).then(data => data);
    });
    
}
```

Then the React Native function which uses it

```
export default function FlightScreen() {
  const [flightResponse, setFlightResponse] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    searchFlightOffers(postData).then(data => setFlightResponse(data.data));
  }, [])

  console.log("TEST: ", flightResponse.type);
```

Is there a more efficient way I should be doing this?

EDIT: To add hopefully a more clear description of the issue, here's the JSX I'm trying to use this data in:

```
    return (
        <ScrollView style={{marginTop: 220}}>
        {
            flightResponse != null ? flightResponse.map(data => {
                return (
                    <FlightCard
                        key={data.id}
                        data={data}
                        onPress={() => {}}
                    />
                )
            }) : false
        }
        </ScrollView>
```

If I add a conditional which checks to see if the `flightResponse` data is null and then map the data if not then this works just fine. Removing the conditional and just leaving it like this:

```
    return (
        <ScrollView style={{marginTop: 220}}>
        {
            flightResponse.map(data => {
                return (
                    <FlightCard
                        key={data.id}
                        data={data}
                        onPress={() => {}}
                    />
                )
            })
        }
        </ScrollView>
```

Leaves me with this error: `null is not an object (evaluating 'flightResponse.map')` .

While technically the conditional is a solution to my problem there must be a cleaner way to handle this no?

**Update:** A solution to this problem is to change

```
const [flightResponse, setFlightResponse] = useState(null);
```

to

```
const [flightResponse, setFlightResponse] = useState([]);
```

and then I can remove the conditional from the JSX.

Comment: what the output from this `console.log("TEST: ", flightResponse.type);` ?

Comment: ```TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'flightResponse.type')```

Comment: Then you need to check your data from API if it correct, you can do `searchFlightOffers(postData).then(data => { 
console.log(data) // check if this response is correct
setFlightResponse(data.data)
 });`

Comment: I have confirmed that I'm referencing the object appropriately. Also I update my post to include more code which hopefully makes the issue a bit clearer.

Comment: Its giving you that error because `null` doesnt have a callable map property. If u did `flightResponse?.map` you wouldnt have to do the null check. And if you give flightResponse an empty array as the initial value you could do `flightResponse.map`

Comment: Actually that error is being produced by `console.log("TEST: ", flightResponse.type);`. Try doing `console.log(typeof flightResponse)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My apology that I didn't see the additional info you have put there. Apparently you have resolved this issue on your own by adding the check for `null`, which, to my knowledge, is the correct usage pattern.

You have to check for `null` because the code in `useEffect` is not guaranteed to complete (because it is async) before `react native` executes the code to render the components. By checking for `null`, you place a guard on this exact situation (and other situations, such as error during fetching data, data itself is empty, etc.).

#### Original answer (obsolete)

Try rewrite your `searchFlightOffers` function in `async/await` style. This way, it is clearer what object is returned. I suspect your current version does not return the data.

The rewrite can be something like this (untested, use with caution).

```js
export const searchFlightOffers = async (postData) => {
    try {
        const token = await getAmadeusToken();
    } catch (err) {
        // handle error during token acquisition
        console.log(err);
    }
    
    const config = {
        headers: {
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${token.access_token}`
        }
    }
    try {
        const flightOfferData = await axios.post(
            "https://test.api.amadeus.com/v2/shopping/flight-offers",
            postData,
            config,
        );
        return flightOfferData;
    } catch (err) {
        // handle error during flight offer acquisition
        console.log(err);
    }
}
```

Comment: The same behavior occurs using this implementation.

Comment: My apology for not having read your additional info. I added explanation why not checking for `null` would result in error.

Comment: Thanks. I also realized I could set ```const [flightResponse, setFlightResponse] = useState([]);``` instead of setting it to ```null``` and it achieves the same effect.

Comment: Yep. That would work. However, I have been bitten by using `[]` before. Say I have `foo = []`. I expect `if (foo)` to evaluate to false. But that's not how javascript works. I have been very cautious of setting default value to `[]` or `{}` ever since.